# Regex и кириллица

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, кириллица

Возникла та же проблема, что и в этой теме **2014** года - [Регулярные выражения и кириллица](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364776/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)
Собстна, вопрос: **за 4 года** в плюсах не появился способ без доп. библиотек (типа boost) использовать регулярки без учета регистра в кириллице? 
Каким тогда образом решить эту проблему, не подключая буст?

Comment: Вызывать стандартные сишные [regcomp/regexec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp)

Comment: В C++ есть регулярные выражения(`std::regex`), которые были там и 4 года назад. Другой вопрос как они поведут себя с unicode. Это нужно тестировать на тех компиляторах, которые Вы будете использовать, т.к. реализация везде разная и могут быть проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

### Простые 8-битные локали (koi8-r, cp1251 ,ibm866)

Для любой простой 8-битной локали всё должно работать из-коробки, само собой, локаль должна быть корректно задана, терминал корректно настроен, а если в исходниках есть не-ASCII строки, то они должны быть правильно подготовлены.

```
// исходник в utf-8
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <regex>

#include <assert.h>

void printRxMatches (std::string line, std::regex rx) {
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), rx);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    if (words_begin!=words_end) {
        auto wi = words_begin;
        std::cout << wi->str();
        for (++wi; wi != words_end; ++wi) {
            std::cout << ' ' << wi->str();
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "<none>";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    assert(argc==2);

    std::regex rxInput(argv[1],
            std::regex_constants::collate | std::regex_constants::icase);

    std::regex rxVowelsWords("\\b[аеёиоуыэюя]+\\b",
            std::regex_constants::collate | std::regex_constants::icase);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
        std::cout << line << " : " ;

        std::cout << "InputMatches ("; 
        printRxMatches (line, rxInput);
        std::cout << ")    "; 

        std::cout << "VowelWordsMatches ("; 
        printRxMatches (line, rxVowelWords);
        std::cout << ")" << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Сборка:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -fexec-charset=koi8-r -o reg-8bit reg-8bit.cpp
```

Запуск (множество iconv'ов симулируют изменение локали терминала на koi8):

```
$ echo "А я есьм строка. уууу! ЁЁ" | iconv -t KOI8-R | (LC_ALL=ru_RU.KOI8-R ./reg-8bit "$(echo "[есто]+" | iconv -t KOI8-R)" ) |iconv -f KOI8-R
А я есьм строка. уууу! ЁЁ : InputMatches (ес ст о)    VowelsWordsMatches (А я уууу ЁЁ)
```

### Мультибайтовые локали

Для поддержки Мультибайтовых локалей (utf-8) единственным переносимым способом на чистом С++ будет использовать широкие символы. К сожалению в самом С++ нет адекватных методов для преобразования между обычной строкой в системной локали и широкой, поэтому придётся вручную доделывать костыли на основе функций из C99:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <regex>

#include <wchar.h>

#include <assert.h>

void printRxMatches (std::wstring line, std::wregex rx) {
    auto words_begin = std::wsregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), rx);
    auto words_end = std::wsregex_iterator();

    if (words_begin!=words_end) {
        auto wi = words_begin;
        std::wcout << wi->str();
        for (++wi; wi != words_end; ++wi) {
            std::wcout << ' ' << wi->str();
        }
    } else {
        std::wcout << "<none>";
    }
}


std::wstring toWString(const char *str) {
    std::wstring rv;
    mbstate_t ps;
    memset (&ps, 0, sizeof(ps));
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    rv.reserve(len);

    while (len>0) {
        wchar_t wch;
        size_t transLen = mbrtowc(&wch, str, len, &ps);
        if (transLen == (size_t)-1) {
            throw std::runtime_error ("Incorrect multibyte sequence");
        } else if (transLen == (size_t)-2) {
            throw std::runtime_error ("Incomplete string");
        } else {
            rv.push_back(wch);
            len -= transLen;
            str += transLen;
        }
    }
    rv.shrink_to_fit();

    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    assert(argc==2);

    std::wregex rxInput(toWString(argv[1]),
            std::regex_constants::collate | std::regex_constants::icase);

    std::wregex rxVowelWords(L"\\b[аеёиоуыэюя]+\\b",
            std::regex_constants::collate | std::regex_constants::icase);

    for (std::wstring line; std::getline(std::wcin, line); ) {
        std::wcout << line << " : " ;

        std::wcout << "InputMatches ("; 
        printRxMatches (line, rxInput);
        std::wcout << ")    "; 

        std::wcout << L"VowelWordsMatches ("; 
        printRxMatches (line, rxVowelWords);
        std::wcout << L")" << std::endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Из бонусов:
 * Это корректно работает для любой локали, и мультибайтовой и простой.
 * Потенциально переносима на любой компилятор поддерживающий C++11 и libc с поддержкой С99.
 * В UTF локалях работает даже эмодзи-безумие.

```
$ echo "А я есьм строка. уууу! ЁЁ" | iconv -t KOI8-R | (LC_ALL=ru_RU.KOI8-R ./reg-wide "$(echo "[а-ж]+" | iconv -t KOI8-R)" ) |iconv -f KOI8-R
А я есьм строка. уууу! ЁЁ : InputMatches (А е а ЁЁ)    VowelWordsMatches (А я уууу ЁЁ)
$ echo "ясвежие" | ./reg-wide "[^]*"
ясвежие : InputMatches (свежие)    VowelWordsMatches (я)
$ echo "ясвежие" | ./reg-wide "[^]*"
ясвежие : InputMatches (<none>)    VowelWordsMatches (я)
```

### Заключение

Вряд ли кто-то добровольно будет это использовать, намного разумней взять что-нить с полноценной поддержкой юникода (icu, boost, Qt, pcre), но как proof-of-concept, что можно обойтись стандартными средствами это вполне пойдёт...